# SecCertificateRef: How to get the certificate information?

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl-certificate, x509

I have a certificate (SecCertificateRef), I can check if it's valid and I can extract a "summary" using SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary.

What is the "summary" exactly? I don't understand the term "A string that contains a human-readable summary of the contents of the certificate." in the Apple documentation. I think, they mean the "CN" in the certificate, correct?

Is there any method to get the clear X509-information out of SecCertificateRef? Does a cast to a keychain-object help?

I want to have something like this and I am especially focussed on the "CN" to compare it with the URL I submitted to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks. (Or any better ideas?)

That is what I want to have:

```
Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
        Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=XY, ST=Austria, L=Graz, O=TrustMe Ltd, OU=Certificate Authority, CN=CA/Email=ca@trustme.dom
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 29 17:39:10 2000 GMT
            Not After : Oct 29 17:39:10 2001 GMT
        Subject: C=DE, ST=Austria, L=Vienna, O=Home, OU=Web Lab, CN=anywhere.com/Email=xyz@anywhere.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (1024 bit)
                Modulus (1024 bit):
                    00:c4:40:4c:6e:14:1b:61:36:84:24:b2:61:c0:b5:
                    d7:e4:7a:a5:4b:94:ef:d9:5e:43:7f:c1:64:80:fd:
                    9f:50:41:6b:70:73:80:48:90:f3:58:bf:f0:4c:b9:
                    90:32:81:59:18:16:3f:19:f4:5f:11:68:36:85:f6:
                    1c:a9:af:fa:a9:a8:7b:44:85:79:b5:f1:20:d3:25:
                    7d:1c:de:68:15:0c:b6:bc:59:46:0a:d8:99:4e:07:
                    50:0a:5d:83:61:d4:db:c9:7d:c3:2e:eb:0a:8f:62:
                    8f:7e:00:e1:37:67:3f:36:d5:04:38:44:44:77:e9:
                    f0:b4:95:f5:f9:34:9f:f8:43
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                email:xyz@anywhere.com
            Netscape Comment:
                mod_ssl generated test server certificate
            Netscape Cert Type:
                SSL Server
    Signature Algorithm: md5WithRSAEncryption
        12:ed:f7:b3:5e:a0:93:3f:a0:1d:60:cb:47:19:7d:15:59:9b:
        3b:2c:a8:a3:6a:03:43:d0:85:d3:86:86:2f:e3:aa:79:39:e7:
        82:20:ed:f4:11:85:a3:41:5e:5c:8d:36:a2:71:b6:6a:08:f9:
        cc:1e:da:c4:78:05:75:8f:9b:10:f0:15:f0:9e:67:a0:4e:a1:
        4d:3f:16:4c:9b:19:56:6a:f2:af:89:54:52:4a:06:34:42:0d:
        d5:40:25:6b:b0:c0:a2:03:18:cd:d1:07:20:b6:e5:c5:1e:21:
        44:e7:c5:09:d2:d5:94:9d:6c:13:07:2f:3b:7c:4c:64:90:bf:
        ff:8e
```

Comment: Since nobody answered your question about what "summary" is:  Summary is a string you can show to users e.g. if you users shall select a certificate from a list of certificates. It contains information that should be sufficient for users to identify a specific certificate, but what information exactly isn't defined also it may vary from iOS version to iOS version.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I couldn't wait for an answer to the bounty, so I found a solution myself. As others said, Security.framework doesn't give you a way to get this information, so you need to ask OpenSSL to parse the certificate data for you:

```
#import <openssl/x509.h>

// ...

NSData *certificateData = (NSData *) SecCertificateCopyData(certificate);

const unsigned char *certificateDataBytes = (const unsigned char *)[certificateData bytes];
X509 *certificateX509 = d2i_X509(NULL, &certificateDataBytes, [certificateData length]);

NSString *issuer = CertificateGetIssuerName(certificateX509);
NSDate *expiryDate = CertificateGetExpiryDate(certificateX509);
```

Where `CertificateGetIssuerName` and `CertificateGetExpiryDate` are as follows:

```
static NSString * CertificateGetIssuerName(X509 *certificateX509)
{
    NSString *issuer = nil;
    if (certificateX509 != NULL) {
        X509_NAME *issuerX509Name = X509_get_issuer_name(certificateX509);

        if (issuerX509Name != NULL) {
            int nid = OBJ_txt2nid("O"); // organization
            int index = X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID(issuerX509Name, nid, -1);

            X509_NAME_ENTRY *issuerNameEntry = X509_NAME_get_entry(issuerX509Name, index);

            if (issuerNameEntry) {
                ASN1_STRING *issuerNameASN1 = X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data(issuerNameEntry);

                if (issuerNameASN1 != NULL) {
                    unsigned char *issuerName = ASN1_STRING_data(issuerNameASN1);
                    issuer = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)issuerName];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return issuer;
}

static NSDate *CertificateGetExpiryDate(X509 *certificateX509)
{
    NSDate *expiryDate = nil;

    if (certificateX509 != NULL) {
        ASN1_TIME *certificateExpiryASN1 = X509_get_notAfter(certificateX509);
        if (certificateExpiryASN1 != NULL) {
            ASN1_GENERALIZEDTIME *certificateExpiryASN1Generalized = ASN1_TIME_to_generalizedtime(certificateExpiryASN1, NULL);
            if (certificateExpiryASN1Generalized != NULL) {
                unsigned char *certificateExpiryData = ASN1_STRING_data(certificateExpiryASN1Generalized);

                // ASN1 generalized times look like this: "20131114230046Z"
                //                                format:  YYYYMMDDHHMMSS
                //                               indices:  01234567890123
                //                                                   1111
                // There are other formats (e.g. specifying partial seconds or 
                // time zones) but this is good enough for our purposes since
                // we only use the date and not the time.
                //
                // (Source: http://www.obj-sys.com/asn1tutorial/node14.html)

                NSString *expiryTimeStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)certificateExpiryData];
                NSDateComponents *expiryDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

                expiryDateComponents.year   = [[expiryTimeStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 4)] intValue];
                expiryDateComponents.month  = [[expiryTimeStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 2)] intValue];
                expiryDateComponents.day    = [[expiryTimeStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6, 2)] intValue];
                expiryDateComponents.hour   = [[expiryTimeStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8, 2)] intValue];
                expiryDateComponents.minute = [[expiryTimeStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(10, 2)] intValue];
                expiryDateComponents.second = [[expiryTimeStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(12, 2)] intValue];

                NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
                expiryDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:expiryDateComponents];

                [expiryDateComponents release];
            }
        }
    }

    return expiryDate;
}
```

I only actually needed the issuer's organization name and the expiry date for my purposes, so that's all the code I've included below. But, based on this you should be able to figure out the rest by reading the `x509.h` header file.

**Edit:**

Here's how to get the certificate. I haven't put any error handling, etc. You'll want to check `trustResult`, `err`, etc., for example.

```
NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge;
SecTrustResultType trustResult;
SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
OSStatus err = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);
SecCertificateRef certificate = SecGetLeafCertificate(trust); // See Apple docs for implementation of SecGetLeafCertificate
```

Comment: could you please clarify how did you get NSData necessary for creating the X509 object? what is "certificate"?
NSData *certificateData = (NSData *) SecCertificateCopyData(certificate);

Comment: Oh, you can get that from the challenge as follows:
NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge;
SecTrustResultType trustResult;
SecTrustRef trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust;
OSStatus err = SecTrustEvaluate(trust, &trustResult);
SecCertiicateRef certificate = SecGetLeafCertificate(trust); // See Apple docs for implementation of SecGetLeafCertificate

Comment: Ugh, that's ugly. Let me put that in the original answer.

Comment: Hi, do we have openSSL library or framework in iOS? I tried but could not figure it out, how did you link it?

Comment: To be honest, I forget; this was several projects ago for me. But, I don't recall having to get OpenSSL built and linked to the project, so I think it was already added to the project when I did this work. It's not a standard library, so someone must have already added it to the project.

Comment: This works but OpenSSL licence is really unsuitable for me. I can't make my company to incluce "OpenSSL" in all marketing material.

Comment: For cocoa you need to add libcrypto.dylib in project. In Xcode "build phases"->"Link Binaries with libraries"-> click "+" button. and add libcrypto.dylib. without this their is linker error in Xcode for openssl.

Comment: @Michael Melanson, how can we do this in swift or swit 2

Comment: did anyone convert this to swift yet?

Comment: @AmitRaj @jatin Doing this in Swift is a simple matter of rewriting it in Swift syntax. And probably converting some of the nesting into `guard let` statements. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: seems like SecCertificateNotValidAfter api exist in https://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-57740.1.18/OSX/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecCertificate.cpp.auto.html .. is it usable?

Comment: also My headers dont have NSData struct available.. can u specify which header file i need to include ?

Answer (score 4):

better just use SecCertificateCopyCommonName to get CN to compare to your required hostname.

Comment: That is OSX only, the question is asking about iOS.

Comment: Sure, in a very restricted sense. SecCertificate.h has about 4 methods available on iOS.

Comment: [SecCertificateCopyCommonName](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1394814-seccertificatecopycommonname?language=objc) has been available since iOS 10.3.

Answer (score 4):

You were right Michael, iOS won't give you the API to do a *full* job on a X.509 certificates. Thankfully it **will** give you access to the actual ([ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)) encoded certificate data. From there you can do your own decoding (not much fun) or delegate it to an existing library, like you did with [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/).

Here's my version that uses the .NET framework. It's mean to be used by [MonoTouch](http://ios.xamarin.com) developers (and MonoMac developers too) who needs to interoperate with `SecCertificateRef` within their applications.

```
public void Show (SecCertificate sc)
{
    // get the SecCertificate "raw", i.e. ASN.1 encoded, data 
    byte[] data = sc.DerData.ToArray<byte> ();
    // the build the managed X509Certificate2 from it
    X509Certificate2 cer = new X509Certificate2 (data);
    // to get all properties / methods available in .NET (pretty exhaustive)
    Console.WriteLine ("SubjectName: {0}", cer.Subject);
    Console.WriteLine ("IssuerName: {0}", cer.Issuer);
    Console.WriteLine ("NotBefore: {0}", cer.NotBefore);
    Console.WriteLine ("NotAfter: {0}", cer.NotAfter);
    Console.WriteLine ("SerialNumber: {0}", cer.SerialNumber);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: (Happy sigh...)  Isn't it lovely using C# for iOS development ! 
I did try Xamarin in December 2014, but although it's fantastic to use C#, I just found the Xamarin Studio for Mac too unstable to recommend to my company.  Looking at this code, I'm starting to miss it...

Answer (score 3):

If for some reason you want to do this without OpenSSL one can use the apple extraction keys. The first one will extract (just) the Subject and Issuer (there are more kSecOIDX509's for most other things, like expiry dates) and pass them for printing.

```
     +(NSString*)stringFromCerificateWithLongwindedDescription:(SecCertificateRef) certificateRef {
   if (certificateRef == NULL)
       return @"";

    CFStringRef commonNameRef;
    OSStatus status;
    if ((status=SecCertificateCopyCommonName(certificateRef, &commonNameRef)) != errSecSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Could not extract name from cert: %@", 
              SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL));
        return @"Unreadable cert";            
    };

    CFStringRef summaryRef = SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificateRef);
    if (summaryRef == NULL)
        summaryRef = CFRetain(commonNameRef);

    CFErrorRef error;

    const void *keys[] = { kSecOIDX509V1SubjectName, kSecOIDX509V1IssuerName };
    const void *labels[] = { "Subject", "Issuer" };
    CFArrayRef keySelection = CFArrayCreate(NULL, keys , sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]), &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

    CFDictionaryRef vals = SecCertificateCopyValues(certificateRef, keySelection,&error);
    NSMutableString *longDesc = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(keys)/sizeof(keys[0]); i++) {
        CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryGetValue(vals, keys[i]);
        CFArrayRef values = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kSecPropertyKeyValue);
        if (values == NULL)
            continue;
        [longDesc appendFormat:@"%s:%@\n\n", labels[i], [NSString stringFromDNwithSubjectName:values]];
    }

    CFRelease(vals);
    CFRelease(summaryRef);
    CFRelease(commonNameRef);

    return longDesc;
}
```

The second function is an over the top try to extract anything you can get your mittens on:

```
+(NSString *)stringFromDNwithSubjectName:(CFArrayRef)array {
    NSMutableString * out = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    const void *keys[] = { kSecOIDCommonName, kSecOIDEmailAddress, kSecOIDOrganizationalUnitName, kSecOIDOrganizationName, kSecOIDLocalityName, kSecOIDStateProvinceName, kSecOIDCountryName };
    const void *labels[] = { "CN", "E", "OU", "O", "L", "S", "C", "E" };

    for(int i = 0; i < NVOID(keys);  i++) {
        for (CFIndex n = 0 ; n < CFArrayGetCount(array); n++) {
            CFDictionaryRef dict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(array, n);
            if (CFGetTypeID(dict) != CFDictionaryGetTypeID())
                continue;
            CFTypeRef dictkey = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kSecPropertyKeyLabel);
            if (!CFEqual(dictkey, keys[i]))
                continue;
            CFStringRef str = (CFStringRef) CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kSecPropertyKeyValue);
            [out appendFormat:@"%s=%@ ", labels[i], (__bridge NSString*)str];
        }
    }
    return [NSString stringWithString:out];
}
```

Comment: SecCertificateCopyValues is available on iOS?

Comment: I'm afraid it's only available in OSX

Comment: This applies only to OS X so it is not answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a public API to do this on iOS. On OSX there are a number of `SecCertificate` APIs to pick apart the X.509 information.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, assuming you're using HTTPS, checking the CN yourself is mostly useless, because the OS already checks to make sure the name is present in the cert.  You're more likely to want to check the public key (for key pinning), which you can get from the trust object without touching the certificate directly.

If the public key matches the previous key, then either the site is legit or somebody has thoroughly compromised the site.