# Displaying untrusted certificate information in iOS app

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6, ios7, nsurlconnection, digital-certificate

In my iOS app, I am trying to connect to a server, which has untrusted certificate.

I am handling this situation by following the procedure as specified in this url:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/urlloadingsystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html

This is working fine.

Now I have one requirement, in which I need to show details related to the certificates such as:

1. Name
2. Location
3. Organization Unit
4. Email address
5. Not valid before date
6. Not valid after date
7. Signature algorithm

Now I have few questions:

Q1. How can I obtain above enlisted information? Is there any cocoa API to provide the same?

Q2. Generally in a web browser it presents all details related to that certificate. Do we need to follow the same behavior in an iOS app?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Q1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8903088/2957168 should completely answers your question. If you need additional explanation - please leave a comment.

Q2: That's your decision - if your server is running your own certificate and you like to keep it this way (like enterprise apps does), just verify the certificate SHA1 or MD5 to be what you're expecting (that's how we do in our apps).

This means you need a class which implements `NSURLConnectionDelegate` or `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` (if you want handlers for the data as well)

And then implement this methods:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    NSLOG(@"connection canAuthaenticateAgainstProtectionSpace");
    if (![Certificates verifyProtectionSpace:protectionSpace]) { //this to verify your own certificate which is self signed.
        NSLOG(@"Bad Certificate, canceling request");
        [connection cancel];
        self.ended = true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLOG(@"connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge");
    if ([Certificates verifyProtectionSpace:challenge.protectionSpace]) { //this is where you verify the certificates again - for non self-signed ones usually.
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, there does not appear to be a Cocoa API to address this issue, However, if you refer to the following information:

Trust Objects and NSURLConnection
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012544-SW6

You will see how to override the chain validation behavior of NSURLConnection which I assume you are using. In the code provided, you can get a reference to a SecTrustRef which can be further queried using the SecTrustGetCertificateCount found in the Security Framework. As you iterate over your certificates, you can query them with SecCertificateCopyValues (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html) and extract any info in the returned dictionary using OID keys.