# How to get the Organisation from an EV Certificate on iOS

Tags: ios, ssl

I've been trying to get the organisation info from an *Extended Validation SSL Certificate* (EV Certificate) on iOS.

I've a `UIWebClient` loading an `NSURLRequest`, but I can't figure out from were should I get the organisation info.

For clarification, I'm trying to get "Banco Santander Chile" from this website when I'm loading the page https://www.santander.cl on my `UIWebClient`, as show on the image below:

[image: Extended Validation Certificate]

Answer (score 1):

You have to extract it from `SecCertificateRef` object. have a look into this thread:

[SecCertificateRef: How to get the certificate information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850524/seccertificateref-how-to-get-the-certificate-information)

Answer (score 0):

To add to reecon's answer, you will also need a list of OIDs to look for. There is no standard EV OID, so you have to rummage for a matching OID from a list of know OIDs linked to the issuers. An OID that indicates EV for one issuer does *not* mean its an EV from another issuer.

You can find a list of Chromium's EV OID metadata at http://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/trunk/net/cert/ev_root_ca_metadata.cc. Wikipedia has a list at [Extended Validation certificate identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate), but I'm not sure how current it is.

---

> ... I'm trying to get "Banco Santander Chile" from this website when I'm loading the page...

Once the EV OID is matched for the issuer, you display the Organizational Name (or other relevant field) from the certificate (`/O=Banco Santander Chile` below):

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.santander.cl:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", CN = VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=CL/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=97036000-K/C=CL/ST=Santiago/L=Santiago/O=Banco Santander Chile/OU=Comercio Electronico/OU=Terms of use at www.verisign.com/rpa (c)05/CN=www.santander.cl
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
 1 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
 2 s:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
   i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority
```

Parse the certificate. Since the issuer is Verisign, the OID you are looking for is `2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.23.6`:

```
$ openssl x509 -in test.pem -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            2d:fb:a1:be:00:e2:96:99:34:a8:b7:5b:90:c9:85:5d
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=VeriSign, Inc., OU=VeriSign Trust Network, OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06, CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SGC CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 27 00:00:00 2013 GMT
            Not After : Nov 26 23:59:59 2014 GMT
        Subject: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=CL/businessCategory=Private Organization/serialNumber=97036000-K, C=CL, ST=Santiago, L=Santiago, O=Banco Santander Chile, OU=Comercio Electronico, OU=Terms of use at www.verisign.com/rpa (c)05, CN=www.santander.cl
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:af:25:f4:cd:20:3c:ed:6c:e6:83:3e:13:1b:c0:
                    98:f8:57:2f:57:01:08:bf:22:df:78:22:5a:37:ea:
                    16:f9:e4:8f:fa:2a:4b:37:2d:57:37:11:8c:29:db:
                    e5:06:ba:05:56:f6:0b:3f:ee:55:98:69:41:85:a0:
                    12:df:5d:9f:09:30:26:7b:70:4b:88:51:05:a5:36:
                    2e:69:c8:28:14:2e:2d:be:7a:13:07:01:9f:eb:23:
                    ea:52:11:6b:72:3f:4e:ba:1d:33:b1:8c:f5:d4:e7:
                    51:f5:f8:5b:86:06:6f:04:02:37:63:b4:6d:e6:a9:
                    4b:34:c4:05:36:8c:7c:e9:f0:71:84:ef:92:38:72:
                    b9:8e:b2:a4:9a:ca:a6:95:da:73:ce:bd:c8:f9:0c:
                    b4:a6:88:c9:e3:b9:a3:34:09:4c:55:3b:ad:ce:5f:
                    2d:35:47:9c:e9:4d:3b:c4:02:1c:22:6b:16:4a:f3:
                    50:2a:86:b2:bc:bd:08:fd:cb:f8:f7:80:c5:86:55:
                    e6:59:e4:c8:79:ba:36:e3:c6:a4:d4:f9:8f:15:20:
                    89:bc:71:64:ab:b4:7c:9e:28:f1:42:f8:16:46:55:
                    97:09:de:a9:78:58:27:22:aa:60:a7:88:64:03:fb:
                    4f:8d:36:01:52:11:47:48:d2:82:2b:de:08:3a:ee:
                    f0:89
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:www.santander.cl
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.23.6
                  CPS: https://www.verisign.com/cps

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://EVIntl-crl.verisign.com/EVIntl2006.crl

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication, Netscape Server Gated Crypto
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:4E:43:C8:1D:76:EF:37:53:7A:4F:F2:58:6F:94:F3:38:E2:D5:BD:DF

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.verisign.com
                CA Issuers - URI:http://EVIntl-aia.verisign.com/EVIntl2006.cer

    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         5b:77:fb:a5:82:d8:fa:cc:84:b5:5c:48:86:fc:ea:ad:2b:cb:
         0f:9e:6e:3b:e6:e5:4a:52:d7:c6:f1:fd:f9:47:a2:2b:b7:32:
         95:4d:bf:74:99:9d:8e:30:3b:71:74:00:3d:59:d5:50:7a:08:
         be:de:2b:d1:69:89:9f:fc:28:e8:2d:28:04:1b:33:fe:20:52:
         84:bd:7a:ad:5b:30:29:41:d1:a2:cd:53:b0:da:50:df:68:12:
         b9:94:6a:5f:32:6f:b5:bb:36:ab:15:81:8d:51:99:bf:4b:5d:
         ee:10:7b:24:bf:87:50:97:94:b4:fe:ad:dc:61:8e:a9:49:a2:
         04:ad:7f:35:a0:4b:0f:ab:7a:a8:86:33:60:e8:12:09:fe:66:
         d5:61:da:a7:69:61:85:26:28:92:39:3a:0c:ec:5c:f8:62:bb:
         b5:72:8d:1f:44:ef:64:0a:4b:e9:af:cd:6a:29:5f:ec:f5:82:
         45:d9:6f:57:2f:ce:51:a4:f9:2c:0e:02:dd:d5:a1:51:ef:45:
         6b:d7:93:55:c6:e0:e1:95:46:b0:7b:fa:cd:05:4b:d9:57:3b:
         c6:0b:d7:f4:51:7b:cd:19:cf:6e:a7:22:05:b7:cf:a8:50:c9:
         20:6f:be:48:85:40:46:61:0f:40:5b:31:49:af:d6:fb:9a:95:
         52:d4:88:1b
```