# SSL Certificate Details in UIWebView

Tags: ios, ssl, uiwebview, ssl-certificate

I need to show SSL certificate details of displayed URL in a `UIWebView` something like Google's Chrome browser shows:

[image]

How to obtain this data from `UIWebView`.

Comment: @utility Nothing really, i check methods in `UIWebView` and find nothing

Answer (score 0):

We are intercepting the call at the network level (rather than the UIWebView), and using `[NSURLConnectionDelegate connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:]`.  This gives you a `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` instance, and if `challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust` then `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust` is a `SecTrustRef`.

Given the `SecTrustRef`, you can follow [SecCertificateRef: How to get the certificate information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850524/seccertificateref-how-to-get-the-certificate-information) and do something like this:

```
#import <Security/Security.h>
#import <openssl/x509.h>

X509* X509CertificateFromSecTrust(SecTrustRef trust) {
    SecCertificateRef cert = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(trust, 0);
    CFDataRef certDataRef = SecCertificateCopyData(cert);
    NSData *certData = (__bridge NSData *)certDataRef;

    const void* certDataBytes = certData.bytes;
    X509* result = d2i_X509(NULL, (const unsigned char**)&certDataBytes, certData.length);

    CFRelease(certDataRef);

    return result;
}

static NSString* X509NameField(X509_NAME* name, char* key) {
    if (name == NULL)
        return nil;

    int nid = OBJ_txt2nid(key);
    int index = X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID(name, nid, -1);

    X509_NAME_ENTRY *nameEntry = X509_NAME_get_entry(name, index);
    if (nameEntry == NULL)
        return nil;

    ASN1_STRING *nameASN1 = X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data(nameEntry);
    if (nameASN1 == NULL)
        return nil;

    unsigned char *issuerName = ASN1_STRING_data(nameASN1);
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)issuerName];
}

NSString* X509CertificateGetSubjectCommonName(X509* cert) {
    if (cert == NULL)
        return nil;

    X509_NAME *subjectName = X509_get_subject_name(cert);
    return X509NameField(subjectName, "CN"); // Common name.
}


NSString* X509CertificateGetIssuerName(X509* certX509) {
    if (certX509 == NULL)
        return nil;

    X509_NAME *issuerX509Name = X509_get_issuer_name(certX509);
    if (issuerX509Name == NULL)
        return nil;

    return X509NameField(issuerX509Name, "O"); // organization
}
```

This is not a simple piece of work.  You'll need to understand OpenSSL's X509 code, the Security framework, and whatever you're doing at the network layer for SSL trust checks.  There might be other ways that you can get hold of a SecTrustRef or SecCertificateRef, but I'm not using them if there are.