# SecCertificateRef: How to get the certificate information in Swift without relaying any third party library

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to get the organization name of the certificate in human readable format in swift without using obj c code and library like X509, d2i_X509

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecCertificateRef: How to get the certificate information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850524/seccertificateref-how-to-get-the-certificate-information)

Comment: @Kamran agreed i am asking is there any alternate code in swift without relying any third party library ??

Comment: Are you asking how to write your own parser? I.e. an ASN.1 DER parser that follows the rules for X.509 certificates?

Comment: @Mats my reqirement is we have a objective c workspace.
There we are  using PODs With Swift Framwork.
For Example HTTPCLient which will deals all http request ..
In side that for security purpose we need to monitor all the certificate organization name with our local array value.

In order to get the organization name of ssl certicate we need to use  library file such as open ssl.which is not in swift(i have checked in our swift security framwork also it is not there) so i have to use this objective c file in swift framwork.
If there is no way ?