# How can I get the a certificate's validity period using Apple's Security framework?

Tags: macos, security, certificate, code-signing, security-framework

I am parsing certificates inside macOS app's code signature and I want to get the expiration date (aka "**validity period**"). According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/certificates/examining_a_certificate?language=objc) the certificate contains a **validity period** but there is no function mentioned for retrieving it.

I am currently manually digging into the certificate and grabbing the value manually using `SecCertificateCopyValues()` from the dictionary but this does not seem to be the proper approach.

How can I get a [`SecCertificateRef`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/seccertificateref?language=objc)'s validity period (`NSDate`) in CoreFoundation or Foundation (Objective-C) using Apple's `Security` framework (not *OpenSSL*)?

Thank you.

Comment: The validity period consists of the time between the "notBefore" and "notAfter" fields. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8850524/589259) (you can guess the `notBefore` method name, I presume). Note that this answer explicitly says that it is not available in Objective C (for iOS anyway).

Comment: Cannot find it for MacOS either, so you have to parse it youself (not recommended) or use a library like OpenSSL...

Comment: OpenSSL has been deprecated a number of years now. I can get the value in a much easier way already than this example @MaartenBodewes but I was just wondering if there was no official Function from Apple as mentioned on their doc. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested in my approach I'll leave my snippet here. Cheers!

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

id getX509ValueforKey(SecCertificateRef certificate, CFStringRef kSecPropertyKey) {
    id value;
    CFDictionaryRef valuesDict = SecCertificateCopyValues(certificate, (__bridge CFArrayRef)@[(__bridge id)kSecPropertyKey], NULL);
    if (valuesDict) {
        CFDictionaryRef invalidityDateDictionaryRef = CFDictionaryGetValue(valuesDict, kSecPropertyKey);
        if (invalidityDateDictionaryRef) {
            CFTypeRef invalidityRef = CFDictionaryGetValue(invalidityDateDictionaryRef, kSecPropertyKeyValue);
            if (invalidityRef)
                value = CFBridgingRelease(invalidityRef);
        }
        CFRelease(valuesDict);
    }
    return value;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    SecCertificateRef certificateRef = NULL;
    NSDate *certExpiryDate = getX509ValueforKey(certificateRef, kSecOIDInvalidityDate);
    NSLog(@"certExpiryDate: %@", certExpiryDate);
    
    return noErr;
}
```