# How can i translate SecCertificateRef cert object to openssl's x509 certificate object in C++

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, core-foundation, secure-transport

i've a SecCertificateRef cert. I need to get Expiry date from it in C++. I've found this [SecCertificateRef: How to get the certificate information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850524/seccertificateref-how-to-get-the-certificate-information) but it seems like it does it for swift.

Closest equivalent I thought I can  do in c++ is :

```
CFDataRef data = SecCertificateCopyData(cert);
const unsigned char *certificateDataBytes = (const unsigned char *)data;
X509 *certificateX509 = d2i_X509(NULL, &certificateDataBytes, sizeof(certificateDataBytes));
```

but this does not work.

OR

I can do

```
    CFDataRef data = SecCertificateCopyData(cert);
    unsigned char* imageBuffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(CFDataGetLength(data));
    imageBuffer = static_cast<unsigned char *> (memcpy(imageBuffer, data, CFDataGetLength(data)));
    int length = sizeof(imageBuffer);
    const unsigned char* i = (const unsigned char*) imageBuffer;
    X509 *certificateX509 = d2i_X509(NULL, &i, length);
```

doesn't work either :(

How can i translate `SecCertificateRef` cert object to `X509 *` . once, I've `X509 *certificateX509`, i can use openssl's `X509_get_notAfter` api to get expiry date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in C++ you can get byte pointer from Apple's API and pass it d2i_X509 ,

```
CFDataRef data = SecCertificateCopyData(cert);
auto dataBufferPointer = CFDataGetBytePtr(data);
X509 *certificateX509 = d2i_X509(NULL, &dataBufferPointer, CFDataGetLength(data));
```