How to verify if my certificate is successfully added to device keychain
I am trying to import a certificate to the device keychain, which I am getting my API. I have used these references to save received data in certificate format. references: (SecPKCS12Import returns different results on iOS 11 than on iOS 10)
and Add Certificate to IOS Keychain in Swift
By doing some modifications to add the certificate to the keychain I have done below code:
 ` func certificateFromCertificate(certP12: Data, psswd: String) {
        let decodedData =  certP12
        
        let keytmp : NSString = kSecImportExportPassphrase as NSString
        let options : NSDictionary = [keytmp : psswd]
        
        var certificateRef: SecCertificate? = nil
        
        var items : CFArray?
        
        let securityError: OSStatus = SecPKCS12Import(decodedData as CFData, options, &items)
        
        let theArray: CFArray = items!
        if securityError == noErr && CFArrayGetCount(theArray) > 0 {
            let newArray = theArray as [AnyObject] as NSArray
            let dictionary = newArray.object(at: 0)
            let secIdentity = (dictionary as AnyObject)[kSecImportItemIdentity as String] as! SecIdentity
            let securityError = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(secIdentity , &certificateRef)
            if securityError != noErr {
                certificateRef = nil
            }
        }
        
                var keychainQueryDictionary = [String : Any]()

                if let tempSecCert = certificateRef {
                    keychainQueryDictionary = [kSecClass as String : kSecClassCertificate, kSecValueRef as String : tempSecCert, kSecAttrLabel as String: "My Certificate"]
                }

                let summary =  SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificateRef!)!  as String
                print("Cert summary: \(summary)")

                let status = SecItemAdd(keychainQueryDictionary as CFDictionary, nil)

            print(SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil))

    }`

I am getting proper certificate summary and also  this            print(SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, nil))
is returning no error. Optional(No error.)
The doubt I have is whether this certificate is properly installed in the device keychain or not. How do I verify that? Please note I don't want to trust the certificate forcefully.
I tried
var keychainQueryDictionary = [String : Any]()
    
if let tempSecCert = certificateRef {
  keychainQueryDictionary = [kSecClass as String : kSecClassCertificate, kSecValueRef as String : tempSecCert, kSecAttrLabel as String: "My Certificate"]
}
    
let summary =  SecCertificateCopySubjectSummary(certificateRef!)!  as String
print("Cert summary: \(summary)")
    
let status = SecItemAdd(keychainQueryDictionary as CFDictionary, nil)

This will import the certificate to the keychain of the device. I want to verify if it is installed successfully.

Your import code is correct.
iOS does not offer a way to view these imported certificates on UI, you have to query them via Security API, this code loops through all certificates and filter the certificate by its X509 Common Name:
func queryCertificate(with commonName: String) -> Bool{
  let query: [String: Any] = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassCertificate,
    kSecReturnRef as String: true,
    kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitAll
  ]
  
  
  var items: CFTypeRef?
  let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &items)
  
  if status == errSecSuccess {
    if let certificates = items as? [SecCertificate] {
      for certificate in certificates {
        var commonName: CFString?
        if SecCertificateCopyCommonName(certificate, &commonName) == errSecSuccess, let cn = commonName {
          if cn == commonName {
            debugPrint("Found Cert:\(certificate)")
            return true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  print("Certificate not found")
  return false
}

You can get the common name with openssl or view it in KeyChain App after imported to macOS.

However, unlike macos, which has a unified spaces to manage certificates and their trust settings. iOS enforces app sandboxing, which means that keychain items, including certificates, are 'accessible' only to the app that added them (or to apps in the same group, if explicitly configured to share access). They are not trusted or accessible system-wide or by other apps outside of your control or app group.
When we say "accessible", it does not mean the imported cert is trusted, you still need:
func SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(_ certificates: CFTypeRef, _ policies: CFTypeRef?, _ trust: UnsafeMutablePointer<SecTrust?>) -> OSStatus together with func SecTrustEvaluateWithError(_ trust: SecTrust, _ error: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFError?>?) -> Bool APIs to handle the trust evaluation within your app.
For example, this gist offers an example to decide if a ssl is trusted in URLSession.

yes this worked. one more query here I thought that i am getting this as p12 certificate so this is correct way to save and import to keychain right? I can use this anything in future right?

Yes, your import code and my query code are both correct cryptographically.

Hi Can I get expiry details of p12 which is imported in above code?

please reply can we get expiry details for p12 which is in keychain of device?

If we are working on iOS(macOS has many advanced security APIs while iOS don't), you will need the help of OpenSSL to parse the data, here is the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850524/seccertificateref-how-to-get-the-certificate-information

hi, one more thing I want to understand is there any way to show this certificate in device settings app under certificate section? or is there any way to make the certificate accessible outside the application?

Pooja, like I said, iOS does not offer a way to view these imported certificates on UI. If you want that, modify queryCertificate function and create a tableView to view it.

The  queryCertificate works only for my project if try the same in other project it do not print any certifiate details installed from my project

Please reply i want to access certificate outside of my project as well

Listen to me, there is no way to import a cert in one app and use it outside your project. iOS is sandboxed, if you want to manually decide whether to trust a cert, refer to the github gist in my above answer.

To Get expiry date from imported p12 , first you need to add openssl to your project and then below code will help you:
let data = SecCertificateCopyData(self.certificateRef!) as NSData

            var firstByte: UnsafePointer? = data.bytes.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
           if let certificateX509 = d2i_X509(nil, &firstByte, data.length)

            {
               var expiryDate = X509_get0_notAfter(certificateX509)
               

               if let certificateExpiryASN1Generalized = ASN1_TIME_to_generalizedtime(expiryDate, nil)
               {
                   if let  certificateExpiryData = ASN1_STRING_get0_data(certificateExpiryASN1Generalized)//ASN1_STRING_data(certificateExpiryASN1Generalized);
                   {
                       let data = Data(bytes: certificateExpiryData, count: 8)
                      if let expiryTimeStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) // [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)certificateExpiryData];
                       {  print(expiryTimeStr)
                          let formatter = DateFormatter()
                          formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
                          let date = formatter.date(from: expiryTimeStr)
                      }

                   }
               }
               X509_free(certificateX509)


Of course, you can extract the .pem file through openssh to view the validity period of p12.

i want to do it in ios using swift also i am having only p12 file with me

Just need p12, can I add your contact information?

not getting what you are asking here

hi, one more thing I want to understand is there any way to show this certificate in device settings app under certificate section? or is there any way to make the certificate accessible outside the application?

Can I add your contact information?

not getting what are you tring to say  here

You can add my skype account and I can help you figure out the problem.(live:.cid.517cf8f37c9d63a2)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
